# Delete custom field for custom object from deleted fields without erasing one by one

Tags: custom-field, delete

When I delete custom fields of an custom object, the deleted custom fields goes to Deleted Fields, I need to empty this Deleted Fields I have about 500 fields I need to delete them once from Deleted Fields not one by one.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to wait 14 days (or was it 30?). They are automatically erased after that.